# How to manage multiple account(user) types in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, database-design, django-models, database-schema

I have to manage Multiple user types in my application,

1. Person - can be actor, dancer, singer, director, cast director, choreographer, music director, etc
2. Company - can be production house, music company etc

I have created User model which has common fields for both these models.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    #common fields

class PersonType(models.Model):
    # persone_type which is a choice field

class Person(User):
    # many to many with PersonType

class CompanyType(models.Model):
    # company_type which is a choice field

class Company(User):
    # many to many with CompanyType
```

Is this way correct?

How do i manage sign up and login for both types of users.

i.e.  While signing up should i create object of User or object of Person/Company depending on what "account_type" field is sent in api data.

If its later option, how do I manage authenticate and login for two models?

Comment: This is somehow opinion-based as it is not a matter of right or wrong. It is a design matter affected by many factors. Nevertheless, personally I would not get mixed up with user models, I would probably use a one-to-one relationship to the user model with any number of "user profile" models.

Comment: Okay I did not get the last part about "user profiles" .. so you mean for each user type like actor,director, dancer there will be different models and AUTH_USER_MODE will be User right?

Comment: This is the main idea. You then can have separate multiple models based on a user profile model, or have a single one with some categorisation field, many possibilities. As I said it depends on many factors eventually.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between AbstractBaseUser and AbstractUser before you start as well. Your user model is more difficult to change once you're further along in the project, and I've found it best to stick with AbstractUser if you possibly can.

Comment: Hi yes I saw the difference but AbstractUser has username as unique key  whereas in my requirement usename is not present (rather only first_name, last_name are present) so I used minimal AbstractBaseUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep things simple, if possible.

```
user_type_choices = (('p', 'person'), ('c', 'company'))

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=user_type_choices)
    user_group = models.ManyToManyField(UserGroup)
```

That leaves room for more user_types later. And then use Django's groups or your own table with "group" definitions.

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    allowed_user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=user_type_choices)
```

To ensure that nobody is added to a group they are not allowed in, simply override `save()` and check that the `user_type` is allowed by the group.

Comment: This looks good !! But only one doubt that my Person and Company models has fields different from each other. Thats why i had created two seperate models for them. should i put them together in "MyUser"??

Comment: Ah okay, then it could make sense to subclass `MyUser` into two separate models. Or, check if there is a way to combine some fields to make them fitting for both types. I would probably try to stick with the one MyUser model.

Comment: Ok I tried but there is no way I can combine the two because Person is living and Company is non living entity so some fields are different which I cant combine.